# how to upload video to google drive using react native google drive api wrapper?

Tags: javascript

```
GDrive.files.createFileMultipart(
 base64 of Video,
 "corresponding mime type", {
     parents: ["root"],
     name: "My file"
 },
 true);
```

is this the way to upload video ?can not get base64 of video .

Comment: Are you having trouble converting to base64? Here's the official docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64